# Исполнение php кода в html файлах

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Здравствуйте.

Проблема достаточно простая:

Необходимо исполнять `php` код в `.shtml` файлах.

Дописанные в `.htaccess` строчки

```
RemoveHandler .shtmlAddHandler application/x-httpd-php .shtml
```

Не работают.

Хостер сказал, что такие настройки указываются в `php.ini` и выложил оный файл в корень ftp.

Внимание вопрос: что нужно дописать/поправить в `php.ini` дабы заработало?

Сервер - apache

P.S. если необходимы какие-то доп. данные - отвечу в комментах. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: На случай если это важно. `.php` файлы интерпретируются как надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш хостер некомпетентен. В php.ini настраивается сам язык программирования, используемые модули, уровень отображения ошибок и т.д. Настройка веб-сервера Apache для выполнения php-скриптов осуществляется в httpd.conf или .htaccess

Если php работает в качестве модуля веб-сервера, для интерпретации php в *.shtml используйте:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .shtml
```

Comment: @mantigatos после прописывания указанной строчки в .htaccess файлы `.shtml` вообще перестали отображаться и браузер просто скачивает их.как я понимаю, `httpd.conf` необходимо запрашивать у хостера?Извините, если туплю. Редко встречаюсь с административной частью процесса.

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как использовать `.htaccess`, хорошо бы проверить разрешено ли его применение (точнее его директив) в конфигурации web-сервера (файл `httpd.conf` во `FreeBSD`, например). Отвечает за это директива `AllowOverride` и использоваться она для установки этого разрешения должна с параметров `All`. 
Обработка файлов php по-хорошему тоже должна быть прописана именно в конфигурации web-сервера, хотя такие, сказать, пользовательские прописи насчет прочих файлов, конечно, обычно пишутся в `.htaccess`.Хотя нередка практика, когда никаких дополнительных прописей делать не надо, достаточно лишь включить php-код в тело страницы, обрамив его соответствующими тегами (`<?php php-код ?>`).
А хостер действительно был не прав.